# List<> user input being overwritten

Tags: c#, list

Okay, I am using an Automobile class that I have created myself. I am trying to use a `List<Automobile>`. I am trying to write this program that will use the `List<Automobile>` and storing the users input in my Automobile class. When I run my code and try to put more than one car in my `List<Automobile>`, it just overwrites the previous car that the user entered. I know that my code is a mess. I am completely new to using `List<>` and writing/reading files.

Just in case I was not very clear in my ramblings. I am trying to figure out why my `List<Automobile>` keeps getting over written when more than one car is wrote to the `List<Automobile>`.

Thank you in advance to anyone and everyone's help with me solving this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Exercise6_DealerVehicleInventory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#region Variables/Constructors

            var answer = "";
            Automobile car = new Automobile();
            List<Automobile> vehicle = new List<Automobile>();

#endregion

#region User Car Input

            /* I might be able to put all of this in one big while loop that way I
             * can have more than one vehicle wrote to this file at a time. */

            Console.Write("Do you want to add a car?\nY for yes or N for no: ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            while (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
            {
                Console.Write("\nEnter the make of the car: ");
                car.Make = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Enter the model of the car: ");
                car.Model = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Enter the color of the car: ");
                car.Color = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Enter the year of the car: ");
                car.Year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Enter the mileage of the car: ");
                car.Mileage = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                vehicle.Add(car);

                Console.Write("Do you want to add a car?\nY for yes or N for no: ");
                answer = Console.ReadLine();
            }

#endregion

#region Delete From In Memory

            Console.Write("\nDo you want to delete a car?\nY for yes or N for no: ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
            {
                int i = 0;
                int delEntry = 0;
                foreach(Automobile automobile in vehicle)
                {
                    Console.Write("#" + i + " = " + automobile.Make + " " + automobile.Model + " " + automobile.Color + " " + automobile.Year + " " + automobile.Mileage + "\n");
                    i++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nWhat item number would you like to delete: ");
                delEntry = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                vehicle.RemoveAt(delEntry);
            }

#endregion

#region Write Data To File

            Console.Write("\nDo you want to write this to a text file?\nY for yes or N for no: ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            string mydocpath =
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            if (answer == "Y" || answer == "y") //(string.Equals("y", answer, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\Vehicle.txt"))
                {
                    foreach (Automobile automobile in vehicle)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(automobile.Make + " " + automobile.Model + " " + automobile.Color + " " + automobile.Year + " " + automobile.Mileage);
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No data wrote to file: ");
            }

#endregion

#region Update Vehicle File

            Console.Write("\nWould you like to add another vehicle?\nY for yes or N for no: ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mydocpath + @"\Vehicle.txt");

                String line = sr.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("\n" + line);

                while (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the make of the car: ");
                    car.Make = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Enter the model of the car: ");
                    car.Model = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Enter the color of the car: ");
                    car.Color = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Enter the year of the car: ");
                    car.Year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Enter the mileage of the car: ");
                    car.Mileage = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    vehicle.Add(car);

                    Console.Write("\nDo you want to delete a car?\nY for yes or N for no: ");
                    answer = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        int delEntry = 0;
                        foreach (Automobile automobile in vehicle)
                        {
                            Console.Write("#" + i + " = " + automobile.Make + " " + automobile.Model + " " + automobile.Color + " " + automobile.Year + " " + automobile.Mileage + "\n");
                            i++;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\nWhat item number would you like to delete: ");
                        delEntry = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        vehicle.RemoveAt(delEntry);
                    }

                    Console.Write("\nDo you want to write this to a text file?\nY for yes or N for no: ");
                    answer = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (answer == "Y" || answer == "y") //(string.Equals("y", answer, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\Vehicle.txt", true))
                        {
                            foreach (Automobile automobile in vehicle)
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(automobile.Make + " " + automobile.Model + " " + automobile.Color + " " + automobile.Year + " " + automobile.Mileage);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing else was added to the file.");
            }
#endregion

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my Automobile class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise6_DealerVehicleInventory
{
    class Automobile
    {
        private string _make;

        public string Make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set { _make = value; }
        }

        private string _model;

        public string Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set { _model = value; }
        }

        private string _color;

        public string Color
        {
            get { return _color; }
            set { _color = value; }
        }

        private int _year;

        public int Year
        {
            get { return _year; }
            set { _year = value; }
        }

        private int _mileage;

        public int Mileage
        {
            get { return _mileage; }
            set { _mileage = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: add this line within while loop: `car = new Automobile();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a new `Automobile` each time you iterate the while loop, otherwise you're just operating on the same instance and overwriting it.

Move this line:

```
Automobile car = new Automobile();
```

To here:

```
while (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
{
    Automobile car = new Automobile(); // create a new Automobile each time

    Console.Write("\nEnter the make of the car: ");
    car.Make = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my issue. Something so simple that I feel like I should have caught but I did not. Again, thank you for the help. Now I have other bugs to work on.

Comment: That's programming for you, it's often something simple, good luck with the other bugs!

Comment: Why do people down vote when you are trying to figure out an issue that you have never dealt with before?

I am asking you because you answered my question and you have a lot of points in their system.

Comment: Perhaps because you posted quite a lot of code. It's good practise to reduce your problem to the bare essentials, and it will help you to find some of these problems on your own. There's a guide here about how to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't worry too much, it's tough when you're just starting out. Keep a thick skin, keep programming!

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am going to read this. I thought it was going to be a long post but I was not sure where the bug began or ended. Thank you for the information about how to do better.

Answer (score 1):

it may seem like the `Automobile` object within the list is getting overridden but you're actually adding the *same* object more than once and just overwriting it's attributes each time.

you'll need to insert this line `Automobile car = new Automobile();` within the while loop in order to make a new object *independent* of the previous `Automobile` object.

```
while (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
{
    Automobile car = new Automobile();
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you too for your help. This solved my issue and I am not working on debugging a different part.